# SwiftUI NavigationView and NavigationLink changes layout of custom view

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have a DetailView() that displays an image, text, and then a map of the location of the displayed image. In my ContentView() I have a NavigationView and NavigationLink to go from the main view to my custom view. Everything works fine, except that the alignment of my DetailView() is not aligned properly as when I view the preview for DetailView(). The text description is showing well below the picture. I have been pulling my hair out for 2 days trying to figure this out, but haven't so far.

[Picture of ContentView()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5KZ.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(picture: "dunnottar-castle")) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                
            } .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        }
    }
}
```

=================== My DetailView()

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    // 1.
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    // 2.
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        // 3.
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.478340,
            longitude: -90.037687)
        // 4.
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        // 5.
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "Abita Springs"
        annotation.subtitle = "Louisiana"
        uiView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}



struct DetailView: View {
 
    let picture: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: -50.0){
        // Picture and Title
        ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
            //Image
            Image(picture)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 80)
                .opacity(0.25)
                .blur(radius: 10)
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                    
                    Text("EDINBURGH")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.bottom)
                Spacer()
                
            }
              
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            
            VStack{
                // Description
                Text("Edinburgh is Scotland's compact, hilly capital. It has a medieval Old Town and elegant Georgian New Town with gardens and neoclassical buildings. Looming over the city is Edinburgh Castle, home to Scotland’s crown jewels and the Stone of Destiny, used in the coronation of Scottish rulers. Arthur’s Seat is an imposing peak in Holyrood Park with sweeping views, and Calton Hill is topped with monuments and memorials.")
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineLimit(9)
                    .lineSpacing(5.0)
                    .padding()
                   // .frame(maxHeight: 310)
            }
          
            Spacer()
            // Map of location
            VStack {
                MapView()
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 310)
                
               //     Image(systemName: "person")
                    .padding(.top)
            }
               
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have the normal layout, you can also use:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(picture: "dunnottar castle").navigationBarHidden(true))
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(picture: "dunnottar-castle")) {
```

to

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(picture: "dunnottar castle").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)) {
```

and it works like I want it to now.